# Routing Skype call to another Voip company

Tags: python, api, voip, skype

As my project to do over this summer I would like to create a program that answers a Skype call using the **Skype API** and allows a user to connect to another **VOIP** provider (through **SIP**) and make calls by dialling through the client callers Skype application.

I understand that the Skype API allows me to answer and receive keypad input, but I'm stuck on actually sending the sound of the call to a SIP client.

Is there an **API/library** that would allow me to take the Skype receiving audio as input in the SIP client?

Is this even possible?

I'm not tied to a language but I had planned on using Python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to hook into your OS' sound processing.
On Windows, you could install [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html) and configure Skype to use those virtual devices. Since nothing else will use them you can just capture and send sound from/to them to "talk" with Skype.